# How To Execute A Method Via Remote Command To Reset Datatable Filters?

Tags: jquery, ajax, primefaces, filtering

In a index.xhtml page as below, I have 3 commandbuttons which, when clicked, redirects to another.xhtml page containing a datatable and, *on complete*, filters it:

```
<ui:composition>
  <h:form id="kpiForm">
     <p:panel id="kpiPanel" >
        <p:commandButton value="filter 1" action="/app/index" oncomplete=" $('#MyFormID\\:MyDatatableID\\:BoxID\\:1').click(); PF('wv').filter();" onclick="rc()" />
        <p:commandButton value="filter 2" action="/app/index" oncomplete=" $('#MyFormID\\:MyDatatableID\\:BoxID\\:2').click(); PF('wv').filter();" onclick="rc()" />
        <p:commandButton value="filter 3" action="/app/index" oncomplete=" $('#MyFormID\\:MyDatatableID\\:BoxID\\:3').click(); PF('wv').filter();" onclick="rc()" />
     </p:panel>
     <p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{datatableController.clearAllFilters}" />
  </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

In the another.xhtml has a button that, when clicked, clears all filters applied to the datatable:

```
<!-- some code ommited -->
<ui:composition [...]>
  <h:form id="OutsideFormID">
    <p:panel id="MyPanelID" header="Some Title">

      <p:commandButton value="Reset Table" onclick="PF('wv').clearFilters()" actionListener="#{datatableController.clearAllFilters}" update="MyDatatableID">
        <p:resetInput target="MyDatatableID" />
      </p:commandButton>

        <p:dataTable id="MyDatatableID"
        value="#{datatableController.items}"
        rowKey="#{item.id}"
        var="item"
        selection="#{datatableController.selected}"
        filteredValue="#{datatableController.filteredDemandas}"
        widgetVar="wv">

            <p:column id="MyColumnID" sortBy="#{item.status.statusName}" filterBy="#{item.status.statusName}" filterMatchMode="in" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="STATUS"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="BoxID" widgetVar="BoxWV" label="status" onchange="PF('wv').filter()">
                    <f:selectItems id="ComboID" value="#{datatableController.statusListCombo}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.status.statusName}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
  </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

When I click in **filter 3** button, the another.xhtml containing the datatable is loaded and, *on complete*, the datatable is filtered as expected. But if I click in another filter button (e.g. **filter 2**), the previously applied filter stays active, resulting in unwanted  filtering; this *previously applied filter* is disabled if I click again on its correspondent filter button.

I've tried to use [remote command](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) to call the clearAllFilters method, but no success.

```
public void clearAllFilters() {
  DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("OutsideFormID:MyDatatableID");

  if (!dataTable.getFilters().isEmpty()) {
  dataTable.reset();

  RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  requestContext.update("OutsideFormID:MyDatatableID");
  }
}
```

How do I call the clearAllFilters method to be executed every time when clicking on any of the filter buttons (in kpiForm) and, *on complete*, the datatable would be filtered ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a cleaner and easier approach:

Your filter buttons' actions should call a managed bean method that clears the filters and then redirects to `another.xhtml`. Something like:

```
    <p:commandButton value="filter 1" 
                     action="#{datatableController.pressedFilter1}" 
                     oncomplete=" $('#MyFormID\\:MyDatatableID\\:BoxID\\:1').click(); PF('wv').filter();" 
                     />
```

And in the managed bean:

```
 public String pressedFilter1(){
      this.clearAllFilters();
      return "/app/index.xhtml";
 }
```

This will clear filters **before** the page is loaded.

Comment: Indeed, your solution is cleanner than the one using remote command. But the problem here is that the clearAllFilters method looks for the Datatable, which wasn't loaded yet, because it is on another.xhtml, causing a NullPointerException. So the action here needs to be executed after Datatable was loaded. But I will accept your solution, since this cleaner way you showed is easier and allowed me to replace the remote command, which wasn't working. Thanks a lot Oscar!

Comment: I see... maybe you could use a `preRenderEvent` to execute `clearAllFilters()` from `another.xhtml`. You can invoke it from `antoher.xhtml` with: `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{datatableController.clearAllFilters}"/>`